# How to remove last character of a complex subquery select statement in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I have this query, now how do I remove the last character of a select statement in this scenario?

```
SELECT  ...,
    ...,
    ,CASE sfo.[Type] WHEN 'true' THEN sr.[Note] WHEN 'false' THEN 
    (
        SELECT Options + ', ' AS [text()] FROM Table1 sa JOIN SurveyResult surRes ON sa.Id=surRes.Table1Id WHERE sa.IsActive=1 AND Table4Id = 4 AND surRes.FormIdentifier=sr.[FormIdentifier] FOR XML PATH ('')

--This select Option returns a record like this:
--'a,b,c,' or 'Male,Female,'
--How do I remove the last character for this instance.
--I saw examples of using substring on the internet but it requires using a variable.  Something I can't afford using in this scenario.


    )  ELSE sa.Options END AS Answer

    FROM [dbo].[SurveyResult] sr
           LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Table1] sa on sr.[Table1Id] = sa.Id
           INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table2] sq ON sr.Table2Id = sq.Id
           INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table3] si ON sq.Table3Id = si.Id
           INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table4] sfo ON sq.Table4Id = sfo.Id
           INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table5] u ON sr.[Table5Id] = u.Id
           INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table6] a ON si.Table6Id = a.Id
           INNER JOIN [dbo].[Table7] l ON si.Table7Id = l.Id
    WHERE si.IsActive = 1
           ORDER BY sr.Id
```

I tried using this

```
SELECT REVERSE(STUFF(REVERSE(SELECT Options + ', ' AS [text()] FROM Table1 sa JOIN SurveyResult surRes ON sa.Id=surRes.Table1Id WHERE sa.IsActive=1 AND Table4Id = 4 AND surRes.FormIdentifier=sr.[FormIdentifier] FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''))
```

doesnt work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of putting the comma at the end like `male, female,` put it at the start (for example `,male,female`)

Then you can easily use `STUFF` the remove the **first** character:

```
SELECT STUFF(',male,female',1,1,'');
```

Obviously the delimited string would be your column value instead.

Comment: trying this one

Answer (score 0):

pleaes try this code for sqlserver

```
declare @abc nvarchar(1000)='a,b,c,'
select LEFT(@abc, LEN(@abc) - 1)
```

Comment: That'll be a bit harder to do when your using `FOR XML PATH` on a column to create a delimited string. That would mean creating the xml twice, which is going to be expensive.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to do (taking care of `NULL` as well) -

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(100) = 'Male,Female,'
SELECT LEFT(@string, NULLIF(LEN(@string)-1,-1))
```